# Run the third party shell commands through a batch file

Tags: command-line, batch, windows-subsystem-for-linux

Let's say I have WSL Ubuntu installed. Now I want to finish the following tasks by a batch file:

- run Ubuntu in cmd
- run Python in Ubuntu
- run Python commands under interactive mode

I've tried batch files such as

```
cmd /k ubuntu "python"
```

and

```
cmd /k ubuntu
python
```

...

Unfortunately, all failed to run python in WSL.

What should I do to run commands in such "nested environments"?

Comment: Have you tried `cmd /k ubuntu  -c python`? Or just `cmd /k wsl python`? (Assuming Ubuntu is your default).

Comment: @Anaksunaman I just tried them out and they work! You may want to consider adding an answer and I will accept it then. Also, I found nothing about `-c` in [Microsoft docs](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/cmd). Could you please provide me a link or something so that I can read more details?

Comment: I have added a short answer. =)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming Ubuntu is your default Linux distribution under WSL, you should try using either `cmd /k ubuntu -c python` or simply `cmd /k wsl python`.

If you would like to read more about using WSL with `cmd`, you may want to take a look at these articles:

- [A Guide To Invoking WSL](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/commandline/a-guide-to-invoking-wsl/) (Microsoft DevBlogs)
- [Windows Interoperability With Linux](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/interop) (Microsoft Docs)

The first article has examples of how to execute commands via WSL in `cmd` at the end of the post, while the second article confirms that the `-c` option isn't required for `wsl`:

> [The] `-c` option for running a single command isn't needed with `wsl.exe`.